# Find if dates lie in interval using R

Tags: r, date, data.table, compare, intervals

I'm using `data.table` but other solutions would also be helpful

I'm looking for an efficient way of checking if three dates fall within a range of each other. I have a dataset with three dates per row, and I would like to check if all three dates fall within the same quarter, within two quarters of each other, within three quarters etc....

Here's some example data

```
data <- data.table( id = seq(1,10),
                      date1 = as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2018-01-01",
                                        "2018-10-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01")),
                      date2 = as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-04-01",
                                        "2019-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-10-01")),
                      date3 = as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-04-01",
                                        "2019-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-10-01", "2019-01-01")))
```

I found an efficient way of checking if all dates are the same (i.e. the same quarter)

```
data[, within_1q := ifelse(date1 == date2 &  date1 == date3, 1, 0)]
```

But how could I check if they fall within broader ranges?  Ideally, my output would look like this:

```
> data
    id      date1      date2      date3 within_1q within_2q within_3q within_4q within_5q
 1:  1 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01         1         0         0         0         0
 2:  2 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01         1         0         0         0         0
 3:  3 2018-01-01 2018-04-01 2018-01-01         0         1         0         0         0
 4:  4 2019-01-01 2018-04-01 2018-04-01         0         0         0         1         0
 5:  5 2018-01-01 2018-04-01 2018-04-01         0         1         0         0         0
 6:  6 2018-10-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-01         0         1         0         0         0
 7:  7 2018-10-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01         0         0         0         1         0
 8:  8 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01         1         0         0         0         0
 9:  9 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-10-01         0         0         0         1         0
10: 10 2018-01-01 2018-10-01 2019-01-01         0         0         0         0         1
```

EDIT: it seems like my purpose has been a bit unclear. I have changed the naming of my variables from q1, q2 etc. now to within_1q, within_2q etc. So my goal is not about which quarter of the year something is happening, but to see if the three dates fall within the same timeframe. In row 1, all three dates fill within one and the same quarter (irrespective of which specific quarter in the year this may be), whereas within the third row, the three dates all fall within two quarters of each other. In the last row, the three dates fall within 1 year, therefore within 5 quarters.

Comment: I can't make sense of your expected output, in 1st row all the dates are in q1 so you flagged q1, but in 3rd row two dates are in q1 and one date is in q2 and here you flagged q2. I'm struggling to find the logic here.

Comment: @MohanGovindasamy I have edited my question to hopefully be more clear on my goal. I'm not interested in which quarter of the year the three dates fall under, but rather in the relative difference between the three dates... Do the three dates fall within the same quarter? Do the three dates fall within two following quarters? etc..

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>% mutate(q1_q2 = quarter(date1) - quarter(date2), 
                q1_q3 = quarter(date1) - quarter(date3), 
                q2_q3 = quarter(date2) - quarter(date3))
```

If `q1_q2 = 0` the two dates in column 1 and 2 belong to the same quarter.

If `q1_q2 = +1` the date in column 1 is in the quarter following the date in column 2.

If `q1_q2 = -1` the date in column 1 is in the quarter before the date in column 2.

And so on for `q1_q3` and `q2_q3`

```r
      id date1      date2      date3      q1_q2 q1_q3 q2_q3
   <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <int> <int> <int>
 1     1 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01     0     0     0
 2     2 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01     0     0     0
 3     3 2018-01-01 2018-04-01 2018-01-01    -1     0     1
 4     4 2019-01-01 2018-04-01 2018-04-01    -1    -1     0
 5     5 2018-01-01 2018-04-01 2018-04-01    -1    -1     0
 6     6 2018-10-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-01     3     3     0
 7     7 2018-10-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01     3     3     0
 8     8 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01     0     0     0
 9     9 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-10-01     0    -3    -3
10    10 2018-01-01 2018-10-01 2019-01-01    -3     0     3
```

---

**EDIT**

---

Dates are never easy to work with.

This is a possible solution that counts up to 7 quarters of difference between two dates. Unfortunately, to automate it is necessary to build a function and it takes time.

Maybe there is another solution, but this one goes.

The idea is the same as in the previous part of the answer:

```r
data %>% mutate(q1_q2 = quarter(date1, with_year = TRUE) - quarter(date2, with_year = TRUE), 
                q1_q3 = quarter(date1, with_year = TRUE) - quarter(date3, with_year = TRUE), 
                q2_q3 = quarter(date2, with_year = TRUE) - quarter(date3, with_year = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(one_of("q1_q2", "q1_q3", "q2_q3")),
            ~case_when(
    round(., 10) %in% (c(0)) ~ 0,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(0.1, 0.7)) ~ 1,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(-0.1, -0.7)) ~ -1,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(0.2, 0.8)) ~ 2,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(-0.2, -0.8)) ~ -2,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(0.3, 0.9)) ~ 3,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(-0.3, -0.9)) ~ -3,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(1)) ~ 4,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(-1)) ~ -4,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(1.1, 1.7)) ~ 5,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(-1.1, -1.7)) ~ -5,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(1.2, 1.8)) ~ 6,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(-1.2, -1.8)) ~ -6,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(1.3, 1.9)) ~ 7,
    round(., 10) %in% (c(-1.3, -1.9)) ~ -7,
    ))
```

The `round` function is used to correctly approximate the result of the subtraction (and thus make it possible to compare the operator `%in%`)

Result:

```r
      id date1      date2      date3      q1_q2 q1_q3 q2_q3
   <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01     0     0     0
 2     2 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01     0     0     0
 3     3 2018-01-01 2018-04-01 2018-01-01    -1     0     1
 4     4 2019-01-01 2018-04-01 2018-04-01     3     3     0
 5     5 2018-01-01 2018-04-01 2018-04-01    -1    -1     0
 6     6 2018-10-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-01    -1    -1     0
 7     7 2018-10-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01     3     3     0
 8     8 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-01-01     0     0     0
 9     9 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 2018-10-01     0    -3    -3
10    10 2018-01-01 2018-10-01 2019-01-01    -3    -4    -1
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer comes very close to what I want to achieve, but I'm afraid it is not able to handle cases span over different years or where the three dates have a difference of 1 year or more. For example row 6 and 10 are not correct, as they should have a value 1 and 4 respectively. I hope my edit clarifies mypurpose a bit better

Comment: I changed my answer to fix the problem. Unfortunately, the method is not generalized and can count up to 7 quarters of difference. If you think this could help you, please consider to rate the answer positively and / or accept it

Answer (score 0):

I like to use lubridate with dates.
Not sure if this is what you are looking for. This code tells you the three date are in the same quarter or not:

```
library(lubridate)

data[, `:=` (q1 = quarter(date1),
  q2 = quarter(date2),
  q3 = quarter(date3))][,qmax := max(q1, q2, q3), by = id
                        ][,qmin := min(q1, q2, q3), by = id
                          ][,samequarter := (qmin==qmax)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, as I wrote in the other comments, my goals is slightly different. I am not just interested if the dates fall within the same quarter, but I would like to know in which span of time they fall within the same range. Or in other words: Do the three dates fall within the same quarter? Do the three dates fall within two following quarters? Do the three dates fall within three following quarters? etc..